# How would I send an HTTP request to another site and have the captcha returned for a client to solve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, captcha

I have seen this website that allows you to solve a captcha from the api to their site for the client to solve. I know that there are services like 2captcha that have it so that all you need to do is send a request to their API and a human there will solve it but I don't feel that that is practical in the case that I want. I want to have bot accounts that allow users to use our API to run functions on the bot In-Game but in order to do this I need to be able to solve these captchas.

## Problem

I want to be able to send an API request (from the Client) to an API website and have the client solve the captcha for that form from our website instead of the other one.

## Idea

I've seen something like this that uses 2captcha with [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer), but I want it to be sent to **my site** instead of 2captcha. The Captcha service that I'm trying to solve is **FunCaptcha** and if for https://roblox.com

## Example of what I want.

[image: Example of what I want]

Answer (score 0):

If you check out this library on GitHub, you'll have a simple script that can bypass Funcaptcha / Arkose Labs without even needing an automated browser.

https://github.com/davidbaszucki/py-funcaptcha

This is far simpler than trying to orchestrate browsers.

Comment: link shows 404 error